# Starting method from class causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase

I am trying to access/call a method I have in my Activity from my class but I am getting null pointer exception when doing so.

Here's the method i am trying to call. This method is in my Activity:

```
    public void start(Context context){

    mHelper = new IabHelper(context.getApplicationContext(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");

                mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true, TAG);

                startPurchase();

            }
        }
    });

}
```

In my class where I am calling it from, I have made an instance of the class:

```
ThemeActivity themeact = new ThemeActivity();
```

And I am trying to call it from an onClicklistener within my class:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                        .setMessage(
                                "Would you like to purchase this theme?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //Here is where I am calling it 
                                     themeact.start(getContext());

                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```

And I receive the following error in LogCat:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
    at test.test.util.IabHelper.<init>(IabHelper.java:164)
    at test.test.ThemeActivity.start(ThemeActivity.java:161)
    at test.test.ColorCard$1$1.onClick(ColorCard.java:67)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

I realized that I was calling the wrong method to start with, and now i am calling the correct method and it still crashes with a null pointer exception with a different error. I have tried to pass a context and it still isn't working. Whenever I try to call the method start(); from the on create of my Activity, it works. But then when trying to call the exact same method from my other class it crashes and I have no idea why. I initialize everything from within the method itself so I'm not sure why it crashes with null.

Comment: Where do you define `mHelper`

Comment: @EdGeorge At the start of my Activity.

Comment: are you calling start purchase from another activity, other than one in which it is defined?

Comment: @HeisenBerg No, I am calling the method from which the start purchase starts from from a different class.

Comment: @Jack `mHelper` is null - you need to assign it

Comment: @EdGeorge I have initialized it when my ThemeActivity starts.

Comment: Well it must be `null`, otherwise you would not experience a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the context variable of the activity as an argument to startPurchase() method

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed my problem by moving my class inside my activity class. I am not sure why it works now but it didn't when I had the class I was using as a separate class.